# Trouble using PIL to change a PNG to a TGA

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to use PIL to convert a PNG to a TGA. I want it to be a non compressed 32-bit image.

Comment: So you've stated your goal, but what is the trouble you're having? What have you tried? Show us your code! If you're getting an exception, show us the traceback!

Comment: I actually deleted the code. It was converting but it wasn't converting to a 32 bit non compressed. I don't know what it was but it wasn't that. Actually I still have the file on my phone.

Comment: import sys
from PIL import Image

sys.path[0]
im1 = Image.open(arguments.texfile) 
im1.save('converted.tga')

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code, rather than trying to post it in a comment. In the question you can properly format it!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I see you're a new contributor, so I advise you to check out [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if, or where, it's documented, but some experimentation shows that PIL retains the compression of the input file. I mean, if you open an RLE (*"Run Length Encoded"*) compressed file, it saves it with the same compression, whereas if you open an uncompressed file and subsequently save it, an uncompressed file will be written.

So, if you are getting a compressed file out, I am guessing you must be putting a compressed file into PIL. So, you need to explicitly tell PIL to override the compression like this:

```
from PIL import Image

# Open an RLE compressed file
im = Image.open('compressed.tga') 

# Explicitly save uncompressed
im.save('uncompressed.tga', compression=None)
```

**Keywords**: Python, image processing, Targa, TGA, compressed, RLE, uncompressed